# Landau Notation/Big O notation

Tags: algorithms, big-o-notation

In our class the following exercises/examples were given:

Compute/find $n_0$ and c from the formal definition of each Landau symbol to show that:

$n^{2/3} \in \Omega(log^8(n))$.

Then in the Solution the following was done:

$n_0=1$ and $c=(\frac{1}{12})^8$.

Show: for each $n>n_0: n^{2/3} \ge c \cdot log^8(n)$.

$n^{2/3}=(n^{\frac 1 {12}})^8$.

Then: $c \cdot  log^n=log^8(n^{\frac {1}{12}})$

And because in general: $m\ge log(m)$,that implies $m^8\ge log^8(m)$.

The 2nd example was this:

$2^{100}n \in O(n^2)$

Then in the Solution the following was done:

$n_0=2^{100}$ and $c=1$.

Show for each $n>n_0: 2^{100}*n\le n^2$

It is true that: $n_0^2=2^{100}n_0 $ and for all  $n>2^{100}: n^2-2^{100}n>n^2 -n \cdot n=n^2 - n^2=0$.

The thing I am the most interested in these two examples is not the solution as much as it is how exactly we evaluate $n_0$ and $c$. I have the following question:

1. We are looking for $n_0$ and c, but somehow we give values to them? And why those values in particular? Why can't n_0=2? and c=34 (for the first example, or even the second)? Is there a logic behind all of this? In the class it wasn't explained, as two why we take the values that we take. I'd like to have a fundamental understanding of the problem, so that then I can be able to find a case by case solution.

I just want to mention also, that I am fully aware of the big-O and big-$\Omega$ notation (small-o and small-$\omega$ and $\theta$ as well).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$ then you are free to choose $n_0$ and $c$ as long as $\forall n \ge n_0$, $f(n) \ge c \cdot g(n)$ (Reverse the inequality for big-oh.)
There is no particular reason to chose one set of values over another, except that you can sometimes make the math easier if you choose wisely.

That said, $n_0 = 2$ and $c=34$ doesn't work in the first example since, for $n=2$:*
$$
n^{2/3} = 2^{2/3} < 34 \cdot 1^{8} = 34 \cdot (\log 2)^8 = c \log^8 n.
$$

It also doesn't work in the second example since, for $n=2$:*
$$
2^{100} \cdot n = 2^{100} \cdot 2 = 2^{101} > 136 = 34 \cdot 2^2 = c \cdot n^2.
$$

* This still doesn't work if you require $n > n_0$ since you can choose, e.g., $n=3$.

Comment: " This still doesn't work if you require n>n0 since you can choose, e.g., n=3." I don't understand this line. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Could you give me another set of values for the first example, and how do you came with those values ?

Comment: @imbAF, it seems that in your definition of $\Omega(\cdot)$ you are using the "greater than" sign instead of the "greater than or equal to" sign. I'm just point out that, for these specific values, it doesn't make a difference which definition you use: neither works.

Comment: $n^{2/3} \ge c \log^8 n \iff n \ge c^{3/2} \log^{12} n$. We know that $n$ grows asymptotically faster than any polylogarithm so we can pick any $c$ and focus on finding $n_0$. Choosing $c=1$ we have $n \ge \log^{12} n$. The derivative of $n - \log^{12} n$ is positive as soon as $n>1$, so we know that if $n_0 \ge \log^{12} n_0$  for some $n_0 > 1$ then  $n \ge \log^{12} n$ for all $n\ge n_0$. We just need to find one such $n_0$. Let's try with a big value, e.g., $n_0 =2^{100}$. We have $2^{100}>(10^3)^{10} =100^{15} > 100^{12} = \log^{12} 2^{100}$, so we are done (here I used $2^{10} > 10^3$).

Comment: I see. One further question. You chose $n_0=2^{100}$. But you could as well choose $n_0=2$ right? Because $2 \ge log^{12} 2$.

Comment: No. Because $4 > n_0 =2$ and it is false that $4 \ge \log^{12} 4 = 2^{12} = 4096$. In fact the condition $n_0 > 1$ in my previous comment is wrong. Sorry about that. However $n_0 \ge 2^{100}$ suffices to ensure that the derivative is positive, so the choice $n_0=2^100$ and $c=1$ works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138146/discussion-between-imbaf-and-steven).